# PHP SOAP webservice authentication not working

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services, soap

I am tried to make a PHP WebService using nusoap:

```
<?php
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";


 function doAuthenticate(){    
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) and isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) )
          {
           //here I am hardcoding. You can connect to your DB for user authentication.    

           if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']=="111" and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']=="222" )
                return true;
           else
               return  false;                   

           }
}

function set_data($test_Obj)
{
    if(!doAuthenticate())
        return null;
    if($test_Obj!=null)
    return $test_Obj['firstname'];

} 
 function get_data($limit_start,$limit_end) 
 { 

     if(!doAuthenticate())
        return null;
     /* you can use mysql and your logic here this is sample array */ 
    $array_rtr=array(); 
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
         $array_rtr[$i]['id']=0;
         $array_rtr[$i]['firstname']='Nikunj';
         $array_rtr[$i]['lastname']='Gandhi';
         $array_rtr[$i]['email']='Nik_gandhi007@yahoo.com';
    }

    $return=array(); 
    for($i=$limit_start;$i<=$limit_end;$i++){ 
        $return[$i]=$array_rtr[$i];
    } 
    return $return; 
 } 
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("productlist", "urn:productlist");
$server->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$server->decode_utf8 = false;
$server->encode_utf8 = true;

$server->wsdl->addComplexType('testObj',
 'complexType',
 'struct',
 'all',
 '', 
 array( 
 'id' => array('id' => 'id', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
 'firstname' => array('name' => 'firstname', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
 'lastname' => array('name' => 'lastname', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
 'email' => array('name' => 'email', 'type' => 'xsd:string') ) ); 

 $server->wsdl->addComplexType('return_array_php',
 'complexType',
 'array',
 'all',
 'SOAP-ENC:Array', array(), array( array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:testObj[]') ), 'tns:testObj' ); 

 $server->register('get_data',
 array('limit_start' => 'xsd:int','limit_end' => 'xsd:int'),
 array('return' => 'tns:return_array_php'),
 "urn:productlist",
 "urn:productlist".'#get_data', 'rpc', 'encoded', 'Returns array data in php web service' ); 


 $server->register('set_data',
 array('test_Obj' => 'tns:testObj'),
 array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
 "urn:productlist",
 "urn:productlist".'#set_data', 'rpc', 'encoded', 'Returns array data in php web service' ); 



if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) ) 
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA =file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

And to consume the WS from.NET C#:

```
productlistPortTypeClient CallWebService = new productlistPortTypeClient();

            CallWebService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "111";
            CallWebService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "222";



            testObj[] arrayPhps = CallWebService.get_data(1, 3);
            Console.WriteLine(arrayPhps[0]);
            testObj arrayPhp = new testObj() { email = "dfdf", firstname = "dfdf", id = "222", lastname = "dfdf" };
            string data = CallWebService.set_data(arrayPhp);
```

**The problem is that the authentication  always failed!**

the C# client not set the userName and the password. why?

Comment: is that php script actually password protected at the webserver level? If hitting it directly in your browser DOESN'T pop up a login prompt window, then it's not protected and the PHP_AUTH stuff will not be set.

Comment: You're assigning with `and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']="222"` instead of comparing as you did for the other one. Probable contributing reason. Try and fix that and run it again.

Comment: @MarcB ,No how i do this?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: good catch. missed that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I fix it this is not the problem, i use PRINT_R($_SERVER) and the values 'PHP_AUTH_USER' and 'PHP_AUTH_PW' are not set

Comment: I don't know how/where it's failing. I went over it char-by-char and couldn't find any errors. How are you calling the `doAuthenticate()` function, through your `set_data()` and `get_data()` functions?

Comment: Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, and if error reporting isn't already ON.

Comment: Another thing I found odd is `arrayPhps` and `arrayPhp` - shouldn't they all be `arrayPhps` or `arrayPhp`?